# Values are being duplicated when being pushed to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

When I run this code I get the last element duplicated for all entries. I am trying to add a new role in discord and save some entries to my json file regarding role details idk but I can't seem to do it.

I have added the declarations for the data nd list variables.

```
let data = fs.readFileSync('roles.json')
var list = JSON.parse(data)
var details = {nickname:"",channel:"",message:"",role:"",emoji:"",raw:"",error:""}
let sections = ['A','B','C','D']
var bar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            sections.forEach(async function (value, index, array) {
                    let role = await message.guild.roles.create({ data: { name: `Section ${value}` } })
                    details.nickname = value
                    details.channel = '12345567'
                    details.message = '1233454676'
                    details.role = role.id
                    details.error = '12443566'
                    list.push(details)
                    if (index === array.length - 1)
                        resolve()
                });
        });
        
        bar.then(() => {
            console.log(list);
        });
```

Output

```
[
  {
    nickname: '', 
    channel: '',  
    message: '',  
    role: '',     
    emoji: '',    
    raw: '',      
    error: ''     
  },
  {
    nickname: 'D',
    channel: '12345567',
    message: '1233454676',
    role: '784672976855498813',
    emoji: '',
    raw: '',
    error: '12443566'
  },
  {
    nickname: 'D',
    channel: '12345567',
    message: '1233454676',
    role: '784672976855498813',
    emoji: '',
    raw: '',
    error: '12443566'
  },
  {
    nickname: 'D',
    channel: '12345567',
    message: '1233454676',
    role: '784672976855498813',
    emoji: '',
    raw: '',
    error: '12443566'
  },
  {
    nickname: 'D',
    channel: '12345567',
    message: '1233454676',
    role: '784672976855498813',
    emoji: '',
    raw: '',
    error: '12443566'
  }
]
```

Comment: What is `details` and where is it declared?

Comment: var details = {nickname:'',channel:'',message:'',role:'',emoji:'',raw:'',error:''}
its declared at the top

Comment: You appear to be mutating the same object repeatedly before pushing it into the `list` array.

Comment: so how wud i go about fixing this?

Comment: Please update your question with the declaration for `details` and `list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the same object repeatedly before pushing a reference to it into the `list` array.

Either declare a new `details` object inside the forEach callback each iteration...

```js
let sections = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
const list = []

sections.forEach((value) => {
  const details = {}
  details.nickname = value
  list.push(details)
});

console.log(list)
```

...or if the above is not possible, push a clone of the `details` object into `list` instead of a reference to the original `details` object.

```js
let sections = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
const list = []
const details = {}

sections.forEach((value) => {
  details.nickname = value
  list.push({...details})
});

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `for...of` instead, don't use `async...await` inside `foreach` loop